# http://domain to https://www in one redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using a single domain certificate (only on the www. subdomain) and want to have all users using this.

Currently i have the following in my htaccess file:

```
## force HTTPS and www. if any of them are not already present
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is, that this seems to lead to two separate redirects:

```
http://domain.com -> https://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
```

This means 3 RTTs for the user until he reaches the correct page. In addition only the second redirect seems to be permanent, the first one (http to https) seems to be temporary,

Is there any solution which directly sends requests of from http to https+www?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one redirect. The target **is** `https://www.%1`. There is no redirect to `http://www.%1` and no redirect to `https://%1`. Only `https://www.%1`.

No idea how you arrived at the conclusion that this rule caused 2 different redirects. Is this what your access logs are saying? Or the browser's network console?

Comment: It is what the browsers network console and also fiddler says... I was also surprised. The first response header tells me it is at https:// domain.com and the second one that it is at https:// www. domain.com.

Comment: @landi are you sure there isn't something else that's redirecting? Another rule or a mod_alias directive? cPanel? It's not cause by this rewrite rule.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I deleted everything else (except of course the RewriteEngine On)

Comment: @landi and you cleared all of your browser's caches?

Comment: Yes I did. you can test it if you want to (just google for tverie, hope it does not count as advertisement this way, else I am very sorry and will delete this comment)

Comment: Sorry I found the issue today. My hoster does generally set a redirect to http:// when you buy a SSL certificate. This redirect was even before the one in the htaccess file. I checked you answer as correct as you were right :)