# Doing a redirect from naked http & https domain to https://www domain in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

this solution [http://domain to https://www in one redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092323/http-domain-to-https-www-in-one-redirect)

Doesnt seem to work for me. I'd like to have..(same as OP)

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

all to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

I've tried a number of solutions and nothing seems to work.

Details:

-I have an ssl installed for the `www.example.com` version of the site.
-Running wordpress
-tried ssl plugins and nothing works
-tried the following htaccess rules, the first doesnt seem to do anything, the second caused an infinite loop

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

and the second try...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?your domain name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.your domain name.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

this one caused a loop..

I'm starting to think that my approach is wrong. Shouldn't one of these work? And if not, how do i go about securing this site completely on the www subdomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do to get it all in one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Obviously replace yoursite.com with your real domain name. Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: So this actually works perfectly for a couple of my sites, but the one that matters it causes an internal server error...any ideas what that might be caused by?

Comment: sorry that me being actively hacked by someone who changed values in my htaccess file.. THIS WORKS LIKE A CHARM!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @PanamaJack Your solution worked great for me.  Do you mind explaining me what each line of code is doing exactly?  It looks kind of like regex to me, but I'm a bit thrown off to say the least.  I will give you more points on your comments :) THANK YOU!